# ReactJS.NET - How do i update props in one component from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, reactjs.net

I have been searching for a whole day now, for a way to update my ShoppingCart (this.props.shoppingCart) with a new item by selecting it from my list of products (this.props.products)..

I have found one way, but it seems really cumbersome and complex, and thats by using Dispatchers like this :

This also requires the npm-package flex if i'm not wrong, and node.js ? This is not ideal, since i'm using Visual Studio and the ReactJS.NET..

So... how on *earth* can i do this the easy managable way ?

**Global Dispatcher:**

```
var ShoppingCartStore = {
shoppingCart: [],
dispatcher: new Dispatcher(),

addToCart: function (item) {

    this.shoppingCart.push(item);

    this.dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: 'updated',
        data: this.shoppingCart
    });
}, 
};
```

**Usage :**

```
addToCart: function (e) {
    var shoppingCartItem = {
        name: this.props.productData.name,
        price: this.props.productData.price,
        description: this.props.productData.description
    };

    ShoppingCartStore.dispatcher.subscribe(function () {

    });

    ShoppingCartStore.addToCart(shoppingCartItem);
},
```

**How to update ?**

```
var ShoppingCartBig = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function () {

    ShoppingCartStore.dispatcher.subscribe(function (o) {
        this.setState({ shoppingCart: o.data });
    });
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to implement [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html).

Assuming you don't want to use Flux:

```
let Store = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      shoppingCartItems: []
    };
  },

  addItem (item) {
    let newItems = shoppingCartItems.push(item);
    this.setState({shoppingCartItems: newItems});
  },

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='store'>
        <ShoppingCart items={this.state.shoppingCartItems}/>
        <Products addItem={this.addItem} products={this.props.products}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

let Products = React.createClass({
  handleClick (product) {
    this.props.addItem(product);
  },

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='products'>
        {this.props.products.map(product => {
          return (
            <div id={product.id} className='product' key={product.id}>
              <h2>{product.name}</h2>
              <img src={product.image}/>
              // I'm pretty sure there are better solutions than using .bind here.
              <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, product)}>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

let ShoppingCart = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='cart'>
        <ul className='items'>
          {this.props.items.map(item => {
            return (<li className='item' key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>);
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Just remember to keep passing things down as props. Keep state as high up in the component hierarchy and use it as little as possible. If these components cannot be wrapped by a single stateful component you might need to find a different solution.

Sorry, I don't know .NET so this is in JS, but the concepts still apply!

Comment: Thanks a LOT Mike !!.. Examples as you have given me now, is the sole reason i just LOVE stackoverflow :) It's easy, working and definately understandable... 

Owe you a digital beer for this @Mike :)